# Return the flow to prevoius step incase of approval rejection. does power automate support this

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have this business process implemented as Power Automate's automated flow when a SharePoint item get added/updated  >> users submit a request >> first approver approve >> second approval approve. incase the first approver reject the flow will go back to the creator to resubmit , Incase the second approver reject the flow will go back to the first approver to reapprove/reject.. now i am not sure how i can return the execution to previous step incase of rejection? i can not find any action inside automated flow to handle this return of execution? i am thinking of breaking down the flow into as many child flows as i can , and call those child flows.. but i will have to do lot of rework to handle all the approval and rejection scenario taking into consideration that in the future we might have 3rd approval as well.. so is there a more straightforward approach to simply return the flow execution to previous step incase of rejection?

[image]